# UseBasicParsing parameter

Tags: powershell, batch-file

In running a batch I am getting multiple errors.

[Batch error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HOId.png)

The initial part of the error message is that "Internet Explorer engine is not available" after that it says "Specify the UseBasicParsing parameter and try again"

When I run the batch from the Desktop all works well, it is only when I run it from the laptop.

The first 4 lines of the batch are as follows

```
echo off
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass .\Scripts\GetQuotes-Yahoo.ps1
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass .\Scripts\GetQuotes-YahooIntraday.ps1
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass .\Scripts\GetQuotes-Google.ps1
```

Could I ask how I specify the "UseBasicParsing parameter" in this batch. Hopefully that will then eliminate the various issues thereafter.

Comment: The error message is coming from Powershell. It is not coming from the batch file.

Comment: It literally tells you the errors powershell is outputting. First one use basicparsing

Comment: So in your `Invoke-WebRequest` command(s), add the `-UseBasicParsing` parameter, as requested in the error message. Have you opened a PowerShell Window, typed `Get-Help Invoke-WebRequest -Full`, and pressed the `[ENTER]` key? _to see all of the help information for the problem command_.

Comment: The error message about "first time configuration is not complete" means you've never opened Internet Explorer and clicked that radio button for Default/Custom configuration. Try to start IE and browse to Google.

Comment: @RichMoss, thank you - that did the trick :)

Comment: @Compo, thank you - had a look, great input

Comment: @Squashman, thanks very much for your time

Comment: @abraham Zinala, thanks very much for your time